# How to determine if my batches are all consecutive?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Company produces three batches per year each using the following naming convention: `YYYY11,YYYY22,YYYY33`

In this case `batch_id =1` all the batches are sequential. However the absence of `batches 200933` and `201022` make `batch_id=2` non sequential.

```
with batch_sequences as(
  select  1 as batch_sequence, '200911' as batch_date  from dual union all
  select  2 as batch_sequence, '200922' as batch_date from dual  union all
  select  3 as batch_sequence, '200933' as batch_date  from dual  union all
  select  4 as batch_sequence, '201011' as batch_date  from dual union all
  select  5 as batch_sequence, '201022' as batch_date from dual union all
  select  6 as batch_sequence, '201033' as batch_date  from dual),
batch_entries as
 (
   select   1 as batch_id, '200911' as  batch_date from dual union all
   select   1 as batch_id, '200922' as  batch_date from dual union all
   select   1 as batch_id, '200933' as  batch_date from dual union all
   select   1 as batch_id, '201011' as  batch_date from dual union all
   select   1 as batch_id, '201022' as  batch_date from dual union all
   select   1 as batch_id, '201033' as  batch_date from dual union all
   select   2 as batch_id, '200911' as  batch_date from dual union all
   select   2 as batch_id, '200922' as  batch_date from dual union all
   select   2 as batch_id, '201011' as  batch_date from dual union all
   select   2 as batch_id, '201033' as  batch_date from dual
 )
select batch_sequence,
       e.batch_id,
       s.batch_date,
       lead(batch_sequence,1) over (order by batch_sequence) as next_batch
  from batch_entries e
 inner join batch_sequences s on e.batch_date=s.batch_date
 order by e.batch_id,
          e.batch_date;
```

I'm thinking I can perform math on lead values, but I'm not getting all the 
batch_sequence values to correctly calculate this.

**Question**

How can I write a query to show that `batch_id=1` had a 'perfect run' and that `batch_id=2` missed some batch_dates?

I'll be content with any result set that can highlight this.

Comment: Is `batch_date` actually a string or a number?

Comment: batch_date is a string (varchar2(6)).

Comment: If it should be exactly the same number of batches it's a simple `COUNT`?

Comment: That won't work because I don't necessarily know how when a batch_id begins  or ends production. It could miss a batch_date and then resume again. The absence of `batch_id=1,201033` would still make batch_id=1 have a perfect run.

Comment: I need to compare each batch_id against batch_sequence numbers and not compare the  count()  of one batch_id with the count() of another batch_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a sequential number to each `batch_id` based on `batch_date` and compare it to `batch_sequence`:

```
with cte as
 (
   select batch_id, batch_date,
      row_number() -- sequential number
      over (partition by batch_id
            order by batch_date) as rn
   from batch_entries
 )
 select e.batch_id
 from cte e join batch_sequences s 
   on e.batch_date=s.batch_date 
 group by e.batch_id
 -- if there's no missing batch the difference will always be the same  
 having min(s.batch_sequence - e.rn) <> max(s.batch_sequence - e.rn)
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f83d29/2)

Data for 2nd batch:

```
batch_date  rn    batch_sequence  batch_date
'200911'  -> 1           1         '200911'
'200922'  -> 2           2         '200922'
                         3         '200922'
'201011'  -> 3           4         '201011' 
                         5         '201022'
'201033'  -> 4           6         '201033'
```